# Cannot configure VirtualBox because correct kernel RPMs cannot be found

Tags: virtualbox, kernel

I'm trying to configure VirtualBox on my CentOS 7.9 server.
However, my kernel version is `3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64`, and I cannot find `kernel-devel-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64.rpm` or `kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64.rpm`.

I tried looking at the following, but neither of them contain these RPMs:

```
wget https://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64.rpm 

https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=
```

With the current installed RPMs, I'm getting this failure:

```
# /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    kernel-devel kernel-devel-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
```

Any idea how to get VirtualBox correctly configured?

### Notes:

```
$ rpm -qa | egrep "kernel" | grep -v glibc | sort -V && uname -r
kernel-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-devel-3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-headers-3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
3.10.0-1160.99.1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why not use KVM / libvirt to run guest VM’s which is supported with standard rpm packages on legacy CentOS